# CSS - scrollable div with hidden scroll bar

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, hidden

I can't get my navigation scroll to work without scroll bars.

I found many examples here, but they are not working.

I tired parent class with overflow: hidden; and child class with overflow-y: auto;

Does anybody knows what's wrong in my CSS?

...........................................................................

Here is the snippet:

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #111111;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font : 12px Arial,Courier New,Tahoma;
}

.layoutWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
   
}

.layoutHead {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #171616;
  color: #444;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.layoutNav {
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.layoutNavWrapper {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.layoutNavWrapper ul {
  width: 240px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.layoutNavWrapper ul li {
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.layoutNavWrapper ul li a {
  color: #e8ecf3;
  background: #212020 url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAEklEQVQImWMICAhoYCAK4FQJAH+kAuF/Y9FHAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 220px;
  height: 40px; 
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.layoutNavWrapper ul li a:hover {
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAEklEQVQImWPIzc31ZSAK4FQJAI0YAylSFqZ7AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
}

.layoutContent {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  height: 100%;  
}
```

```html
 <div class="layoutWrapper">
 
  <div class="layoutNav">
   <div class="layoutNavWrapper">
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="">Startseite</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Mein Profil</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Profil bearbeiten</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>     
    </ul>

   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="layoutContent">
   <div class="layoutHead">
    >_ Keyboard Hobby 
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What scroll bar are you trying to get rid of?

Comment: My left navigation has a scrolling bar, I want it scrollable without a scoll bar.

Comment: Here is an example: https://codepen.io/JonAnderDev/pen/XJNOPr , this way work on all browthers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add some `padding-right` in order to hide the scroll-bars.

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #111111;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font : 12px Arial,Courier New,Tahoma;
}

.layoutWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.layoutHead {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #171616;
  color: #444;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.layoutNav {
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.layoutNavWrapper {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px; /* added */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.layoutNavWrapper ul {
  width: 240px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.layoutNavWrapper ul li {
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.layoutNavWrapper ul li a {
  color: #e8ecf3;
  background: #212020 url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAEklEQVQImWMICAhoYCAK4FQJAH+kAuF/Y9FHAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 220px;
  height: 40px; 
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.layoutNavWrapper ul li a:hover {
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAEklEQVQImWPIzc31ZSAK4FQJAI0YAylSFqZ7AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
}

.layoutContent {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  height: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="layoutWrapper">
 
  <div class="layoutNav">
   <div class="layoutNavWrapper">
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="">Startseite</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Mein Profil</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Profil bearbeiten</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="">Platzhalter</a>
     </li>     
    </ul>

   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="layoutContent">
   <div class="layoutHead">
    >_ Keyboard Hobby 
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try this to hide the scrollbar.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Cool ! Ok for chrome or safari, but not for Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a previous answer: [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll).

To fix yours, I've adapted the above answer thus:

```css
.layoutNav {
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
}

.layoutNavWrapper {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding-right: 17px; /* Increase/decrease this value for cross-browser compatibility */
}
```

Here is a working [pen](https://codepen.io/robwelan/pen/gXOMRE).

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox quantum:
  `.your-class{
      scrollbar-color: transparent transparent; 
   }`

For Safari, Chrome:
  `::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }`